# Toggle divs without using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to toggle a `<div>`, but my requirement is that it must work with `javascript` turned off.  I would like to select a hyperlink that states "modify search" and the div that contains the search criteria displays.

I've found a TON of demos using `jQuery`, but they all require `javascript` enabled.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: of course jQuery required javascript to be enabled... it's a javascript library...

Comment: Your best bet would be to have the link reload the page then.

Comment: Can you use `CSS 3` selectors?

Answer (score 47):

[Here you go, skipper!](http://jsfiddle.net/gSPqX/1/) (*edit* — updated for science)

HTML:

```
<label for=cb>Click Here</label>
<input type='checkbox' style='display: none' id=cb>
<div>
    Hello. This is some stuff.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input:checked + div { display: none; }
```

*edit* — an additional note: `display: none` will cause certain browsers (IE) to pay no attention to the `<input>` checkbox. Instead of hiding it with the `display` CSS attribute, you can "move" it offscreen with something like `position: absolute; left: -10000px;`.

Comment: +1, but it forces him to change the DOM, and use CSS3 selectors, which are probably a lot more users with them off then javascript off... but +1 anyway.

Comment: @gdoron no pain, no gain! :-) I don't know how widely-supported those things are; I'll check "caniuse" ...

Comment: @gdoron I think the `+` is actually CSS2.1, but it wasn't supported widely. IE7 should even do it now however. I think `:checked` is probably the limiting factor.

Comment: @Pointy. The main issue as I see it is indeed the CSS3 and what if the div is somewhere deep in other subtree. Focus on javascript off, Ohhh Lord!

Comment: @gdoron I completely agree; CSS selectors are a really terrible way to write software :-)

Comment: @Pointy. On the other hand, they won't fire you as you're the only one knowing what the heck is going on in the software... I updated my answer to say **it's practically impossible**. But your answer is better, and I hope he'll accept this.

Comment: Mmmh. The demo works in Firefox but not in Chrome (19.0.1084.56). The text changes, but the div is always visible. Which browser did you test this in?

Comment: @FelixKling really?!?  I *thought* it worked ... hold on and I'll check. There's nothing really exotic about it ...

Comment: I know... I'm wondering too. Cannot exclude that I did something wrong though ;)

Comment: @FelixKling it looks like Chrome is just buggy - if you do some poking at it with the Chrome debugger (the "Elements" tool), the CSS sometimes kicks in after the fact.

Comment: Safari behaves in almost the exact same way, so I suspect it's a webkit issue.

Comment: I still cannot get it to work, but I believe you :) It's not worth investigating further since we all seem to agree that this should not be done in real code with CSS ;) Nice idea though! Just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 20):

The [`<details>` element](https://devdocs.io/html/element/details) does what you ask without any CSS or JavaScript applied.

It is of course not a `div`, so it doesn't answer your question literally, but I read your requirement being having some content you wish to conditionally reveal or conceal.

> The `<details>` creates a disclosure widget in which information is visible only when the widget is toggled into an "open" state. A summary or label can be provided using the `<summary>` element.

Unfortunately [browser support for `<details>`](https://caniuse.com/#search=details) is less than perfect, IE and Edge currently having no support at all. Edge status is [Under Consideration](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/detailssummary). Development of IE is stopped so it will never gain support.

Comment: May be obvious, but the chromium-based version of Edge (76+) will support `<details>`

Comment: Since IE11 is getting axed this month, I think this should be the accepted answer for this question.

Comment: Exactly what I needed on Mac for a QuickLook plugin. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Here is the simple example follow this and you will be able to create toggle using css without any JAVASCRIPT and JQUERY. You can also add animations using css without JQUERY. CSS3 is AWESOME! :)

```css
.box{width:200px;
height:0;
background:red;
transition:all 0.4s linear;}
input:checked ~ .box{height:220px;}
```

```html
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" style="visibility:hidden">
<label for="toggle"> CLICK ME </label>
<div class="box"> </div>
```

Comment: I can verify that this works perfectly on desktop Chromium 27 and Firefox 40. On Android... Firefox 60 only works sometimes. Chrome 66, Dolphin 12 and Via 3.3.2 work fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can't toggle on clicks without javascript. End.

**Update:**

If you can use `CSS 3` selectors, you'll have to change your DOM structure and use `CSS 3` selectors without a library that covers old browsers which are probably a lot more common than users with javascript off, You can usee @pointy answer with `:selected`.

So I would say, **practically** it's still **impossible**...!

Comment: BTW, I would change the _"requirements"_ or the work place... javascript disabled... ?!

Comment: @Pointy. He wants to toggle the `<div>` not the checked anchor.

Comment: @gdoron: See here I again got downvoted even though OP agrees and see here who dont like it :) <it is not horrible reply that I get downvote> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986159/automatically-scroll-droppable-div-whilst-dragging/10986522#10986522 **And** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025470/jquery-ui-sortable-scrolling-jsfiddle-example/ just feeling bit dumbfound so pinging ya! Howz it going? did team stackoverflow mentioned anything about this last time. :) cheers man!

Answer (score 5):

For a little more polished version of the accepted answer, a common practice is to combine a hidden checkbox + label to be able to have a clickable label on screen that maps to a hidden backing value that is available to both JavaScript ([`.checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/checkbox#p-checked)) and to CSS ([`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked))

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='css-toggle-switch' checked='checked' class='css-toggle-switch'>
<label for='css-toggle-switch' class='btn'>Error Details</label>
<div class='css-toggle-content'>
   <pre><code>Unexpected StackOverflow</code></pre>
</div >
```

*By putting our checkbox first*, we can drive CSS decisions based on the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) selector.  We can grab subsequent elements with the [adjacent sibling select `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) or the [general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```css
 /* always hide the checkbox */
.css-toggle-switch { display: none; }

/* update label text to reflect state */
.css-toggle-switch         + label:before { content: "Hide "; }
.css-toggle-switch:checked + label:before { content: "Show "; }

 /* conditionally hide content when checked */
.css-toggle-switch:checked ~ .css-toggle-content  { display: none; }

/* make the label look clickable */
.css-toggle-switch + label {
   cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
```

[image: Screengrab Demo]

#### Working Demo in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/cd5hpp2d/) & StackSnippets

```css
.css-toggle-switch { display: none; }
.css-toggle-switch         + label:before { content: "Hide "; }
.css-toggle-switch:checked + label:before { content: "Show "; }
.css-toggle-switch:checked ~ .css-toggle-content  { display: none; }

.css-toggle-switch + label {
   cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}



/* just some styles to make the demo a little more pleasant */
.btn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #dddddd;
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #dddddd;
          box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #dddddd;
}
.panel {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #ffe06d;
    border: 1px solid #d69e01;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
pre {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background: #eaeaea;
  border: 1px solid grey;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <input type='checkbox' id='css-toggle-switch' 
          checked='checked' class='css-toggle-switch'>
  <label for='css-toggle-switch' class='btn'>
    Error Details
  </label>
  <div class='css-toggle-content'>
     <pre><code>Unexpected StackOverflow</code></pre>
  </div >
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

About three years late to the party, but I found this when I was looking to do the same thing, for a mobile menu, and subsequently found a very good solution, so I thought I'd post it for whoever else comes a-hunting.

The basic idea was from this article: http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/build-smart-mobile-navigation-without-hacks-6122800. I think
I've used a slightly simpler approach (stumbled on while setting it all
up). This hides / displays the navigation, by clicking the Menu button.

In the CSS, nav is set as "hidden" and nav:target is set to display. The page has two menu buttons, using the same image, both have class menubutton, absolute position in the same place.
menbuttonON has index 1000, sits outside nav in the html menubuttonOFF has index 1001, but sits inside nav, so it's invisible at first

In the HTML, clicking menubuttonON links to nav, which is then target, so
it displays. Inside that nav is menubuttonOFF, with a higher z-index
than menubutton ON, so that's on top now. Clicking menubuttonOFF links
back to menubuttonON, so nav isn't the target, and disappears, taking
menubuttonOFF with it.

Simplified CSS (without site-specific formatting):

```
nav {display: none;}
nav:target {display: block !important;}
.menubutton { position: absolute;
text-align: right;
top: 0;
margin-top: 14%;} /* This margin puts it below the header logo */
.menubuttonON {z-index: 1000;}
.menubuttonOFF {z-index: 1001;}
```

HTML

```
<header> <!-- logo here --> </header>
<div class="menubutton menubuttonON" name="buttonON"><a href="#nav"><img src="../Images/menubutton.png">MENU</a></div>

<nav id="nav" name="nav">

<div class="menubutton menubuttonOFF"><a
href="#buttonON"><img src="../Images/menubutton.png">CLOSE</a></div>
<ul> <!-- all the navigation stuff --> </ul>
</nav>
```

You can see it working here: http://www.thewritersgreenhouse.co.uk/storyelements_resources/storyelements.htm.

Comment: This is a pretty solid solution if you're willing to add some extra HTML.

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is impossible without JavaScript. *(Or, [as @Pointy has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11023915/362536), CSS3 selectors.)*

You will have to modify your requirements, or better yet, just display the form by default and hide for JavaScript users (if necessary).  Your page can work for everyone, and have unimportant features disabled for those that cannot use them.

Comment: Don't worry practically it's still impossible...!

Answer (score 1):

No Javascript, no toggling. There are some pseudo CSS3 methods, but if you have to support JS off, you're certainly not supporting CSS3.

Comment: Not necessarily so.  Users with JavaScript disabled often run modern browsers.  Supporting users without JavaScript isn't about backwards compatibility with browsers.  Even very early browsers (IE 3.0 and such) supported JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you must use JS to achieve toggling of divs.  If you want your website to work with javascript disabled, you need to design your website to fail gracefully when javascript isn't available. In other words, your website should NOT rely on JavaScript to function.  Ex: AJAX forms should fall back to HTTP submit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without using either Javascript or sending another request.

If you can live with the extra request (that is, an added page load is OK), then the most straightforward solution is to point the link to the current URL, but add a query string parameter, e.g. `http://example.com/current-page?showsearch=1`. Then, on the server, check if the `showsearch` parameter is set, and if so, initialize the search div to be visible.

Of course you will have to take care that the rest of your page state survives the request; you may have to use a form to be able to carry over any data the user may have entered, and this most likely means your link can't be a link, but has to be a button (because links cannot trigger form submits without Javascript).

Comment: Surprise, surprise!  Hello, CSS3!

Answer (score 0):

The way to make this work with JS disabled is have the hyperlink have some href that accomplishes the task you desire - like:

/the/original/url?advanced-search=true

where the web server delivers different content when ?advanced-search=true is there.  if JS is enabled, the jquery code you've researched should just cancel the original action.