# How to make my links open a 'popup' window

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <div id="box1"> <a href="#"><img src="images/pskeksmall.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <h2 class="subtitle">Student Makes our new website</h2>
        <p>We are very proud to announce that our new website was designed and created by Charlie Johnson</p>
        <ul class="contact">
            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-facebook"><span></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-dribbble"><span>Pinterest</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="icon icon-tumblr"><span>Google+</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

What I want this to do is open in a small window, and have more information on the topic. I've only looked briefly at JavaScript, so if there's an easy way to do this without JScript it would be preferable. I need to do this for 3 other boxes too.

EDIT: Maybe I wasn't very clear, I don't want to user to leave the page, at all, using Chrome I know that popups open in the small dialogue box, this is what I want the information to be provided by. If this isn't possible, is there a way that I could change the information in the main text area, without changing the page?

EDIT 2: OK so I found this on [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed.";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>JavaScript in Head</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```

So I'm now wondering if it would be possible to use my image in substitute to the button, and change my  instead of the paragraph used above.

Comment: basically you want to open a div of information on hover to any link?

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar Sorta, but instead of hover I want it when they click it.

Comment: Read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023816/toggle-divs-without-using-javascript

Comment: By the way what is the problem with javascript??? Because click events may be efficiently performed with one or two lines of jquery , while css codes will make you confused sometimes.

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar I have only briefly touched on JScript, so I'd prefer not to have to learn a new language for a such a small part of a website.

Comment: Charlie, all i want to say is, click events that opens up a new div, cannot be performed by css. Either you may use bootstrap css library and use dropdown menu or You have to unwillingly use jquery. I think, bootstrap will not require you to learn a new language. You have to just learn about some class names. That's it.

Comment: "click events that opens up a new div, cannot be performed by css." - In fact, this *is* possible, using a # anchor and the :target pseudo-class. See my post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a *CSS-only* example of how you can *click-to-reveal* a (usually hidden) element which can then display more information.

No javascript needed!

```css
.more-info {
 display: none;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,127,1);
 padding: 6px;
 border: 2px solid rgba(127, 0, 0, 1);
 }

#item1:target, #item2:target {
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#item1">Click me for more info about Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#item2">Click me for more info about Item 2</a></li>
</ul>

<p id="item1" class="more-info">Now you can read more information about Item 1</p> 
<p id="item2" class="more-info">Now you can read more information about Item 2</p>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks so much Rounin. Is there a way to toggle this? Or will it just be there until the user refreshes the page?

Comment: Once the browser url has a `# fragment` at the end of it, you can't get rid of it - you can only swap it for another `# fragment` (by clicking on another in-page anchor). The only way to stay on the page and get rid of the `# fragment` (without javascript) is by refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

The easy HTML way to do this is to use a tags with the target attribute:

```
<a href="/some/path" target="_blank">Try it</a>
```

A tag documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: I've used the `<target="_blank">` tag in other parts of the website, but I still have to create a new webpage as the `href`. Is there a way to change the text on the current html page, or would I have to create a new page for each story?

Comment: You have to put the HTML somewhere, either on a new page, or the existing one.  Your initial question was "What I want this to do is open in a small window".  In order to do that you'll need a new page.