# interchange the positions of html/css button

Tags: html, css

I created a on/off button using html/css. When on or off button is clicked it will link to python script using href tag. But i dont want buttons to appear seperate. so what i am trying is When ON button is clicked, off button should go invisible or hidden and vice-versa. When one button is clicked it should swap its position with another button. So it will appear as single button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
 title>{{ title }}</title>
 <style type="text/css">
   body {
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
   }      
   .large_button {
       position: absolute;
       width: 32%;
       height: 23%;
       text-align: center;
       text-decoration: none;
       font-size: 400%;
   }
   #On {
     background-color: #ffe4c4;
     color: #000000;
     top: 1;
     tect-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #5C4E17;
   }
   #On {
     background-color: #ffe4e1;
     color: #66cd00;
     left: 34%;
     top: 1;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #5C4E17;
   }
   #Off {
     background-color: #ffe4e1;
     color: #66cd00;
     left: 68%;
     top: 1;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #5C4E17;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>
      <a href="/On" id="On" class="large_button">ON</a>
  </h1>
  <h1>
      <a href="/Off" id="On" class="large_button">OFF</a>
  </h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, Something like this might help.

Calling a javascript function on click.

```
<script>
    var hidden = false;
    function action() {
        hidden = !hidden;
        if(hidden) {
            document.getElementById('ON').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('OFF').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chouhan... Will try this. But is it possible to do without Javascript. Coz i have 0 knowledge in java.

Comment: you might want to check this out: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023816/toggle-divs-without-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can add Jquery based on id and class like below

```
<body>
  <h1>
      <a href="/On" id="On" class="on_class">ON</a>
  </h1>
  <h1>
      <a href="/Off" id="Off" class="off_class">OFF</a>
  </h1>
</body> 

$(document).ready(function () 
{
            $('#On').hide();

            $('#Off').click(function () {
                if ($('#Off').hasClass('off_class'))
                    $('#off').removeClass("off_class").addClass("large_button");              

            });

        });
```

Comment: Thanks @AJAY  Will try this. But is it possible to do without Javascript. Coz i have 0 knowledge in java.

Comment: Thanks again @AJAY im still struggling... i get only off button. Nothing happens when i click on that. Can you help me further?

Comment: I think you only show and hide options 
`$(document).ready(function () 
{
            $('#On').hide();

            $('#Off').click(function () {
                if ($('#Off').hasClass('off_class'))
                      $('#Off').hide();
        $('#On').show();
            });

            $('#on').click(function () {
                if ($('#on').hasClass('on_class'))
                      $('#On').hide();
        $('#Off').show();
            });

        });`