# How to toggle between two images on click without using JavaScript

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In a HTML document, I have `<img src="cat-thumbnail.jpg">`. When the user clicks on the image, I want to display another image instead: `<img src="cat-full.jpg">`. The user should be able to toggle between these two images by clicking on the image. Is it possible to do this without using JavaScript? If so, how?

EDIT:
This is the HTML document in question:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Cat image</h1>
    <img src="cat-thumbnail.jpg">
    <!-- <img src="cat-full.jpg"> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need JS for this, you can't do such stuff with HTML alone.

Comment: @cloned No, [that's incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023816/toggle-divs-without-using-javascript). But the OP needs to demonstrate what they've tried and show us a [mcve]

Comment: @j08691 Thank you. I have found the answer.

Comment: @j08691 What kind of "minimal reproducible example" should I add to the question? The HTML in the question is about as minimal as it gets. One is able to reproduce the situation by simply adding the two img tags into any plain HTML document.

Comment: @Flux For the minimal example, the HTML you posted in your answer would be a start, along with any CSS that you have applied to it. In your case, the structure/hierarchy of your images is very important to a solution without JavaScript.

Comment: @j08691 The HTML file in question is truly minimal, with no CSS applied. I have added the full HTML file to the question.

Comment: @j08691 it is certainly possible to do this with HTML only when the user clicks on a checkbox. But not possible to do this when the user clicks on an image (which is the original question). Maybe if you wrap the image in a label together with the checkbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution that works without JavaScript:

HTML:

```html
<label>
  <input class="image-toggler" type="checkbox">
  <img class="thumbnail" src="cat-thumbnail.jpg">
  <img class="full" src="cat-full.jpg" loading="lazy">
</label>
```

CSS:

```css
/* Hide checkbox */
input.image-toggler {
  display: none;
}

/* When checkbox is unchecked, show thumbnail and hide full image */
img.full {
  display: none;
}

/* When checkbox is checked, hide thumbnail and show full image */
input.image-toggler:checked + img.thumbnail {
  display: none;
}

input.image-toggler:checked + img.thumbnail + img.full {
  display: block;
}
```

This shows the thumbnail when the hidden checkbox is unchecked, and shows the full image when the hidden checkbox is checked. `loading="lazy"` is for delaying the loading of the full image until the user needs it, but it is not a standard attribute.