How do I make an image change when I click it, while only using HTML?
I'm doing a final project for my computer science class, where we have to make a website about any topic in HTML/CSS. The compiler we use doesn't support JavaScript, so I can't use that. The way I was planning on doing it was to make it so when you clicked a white square, it would turn into a black one. I'm not sure how to accomplish this on a larger scale, but I have seen other people with similar questions before so I think it's possible. Here is my HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="canvas">
      <img src="white.jpeg" class="image">
      <img src="white.jpeg" class="image">
      <img src="white.jpeg" class="image">
      <img src="white.jpeg" class="image">
      <img src="white.jpeg" class="image">
      <img src="white.jpeg" class="image">
      <img src="white.jpeg" class="image">
      <img src="white.jpeg" class="image">
      <!—there will be 7 more rows of this—>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

CSS:
.image-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
.image {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float:left;
}
.canvas{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: black solid 1px;
}

I tried to use some code from a different solution but I wasn't sure how to apply it to my problem.

There are some ways to achieve similar behavior in pure CSS, but it usually consists of techniques that rely on mouse focus, which will change once the mouse moves or clicks something else. It would be great if you shared what compiler you're using, since it's weird for a "compiler" to only support static content in this case.

@Shape We are using studio.code.org, its a high school class so we are on iPads.

It's the first time I'm seeing this tool and are therefore unfamiliar with it, but maybe it's possible to inspect the code that's produced by the compiler and add a piece of javascript afterwards to add the click/slide functionality.
Many compilers mess up element class names or abstract them away, but if you can set custom element classes/IDs and they remain in the compiled code, it may be possible to reference them inside of JS that you may add in a second step, after your app is compiled, because sadly, this seems like something that requires scripting.

@Shape I see. I read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173012/how-to-toggle-between-two-images-on-click-without-using-javascript and thought i might be able to. I’ll ask my teacher to see if i could use a different compiler.

@user23989298 Does Javascript onclick simulation using only css and html (without javascript) help?

You don't need JS, and maybe you aren't allowed it as this is classwork. Have you considered using inputs of type checkbox or radio plus label elements [i.e. are you allowed to change the HTML?]

Yes if you are not obliged to use img tag you can as suggested by @A Haworth use checkbox

@mehdi I was not suggesting that an img element should not be used.

@A Haworth interesting I can see what you meant in the posted answer below. Always interesting to see your answers and suggestions. Thé answer below deserve a +1 as well

@AHaworth What do you mean change the HTML? I can do basically anything within HTML/CSS as far as i can tell.

I meant was it OK for you to add things to the HTML? If so the answer already given seems to be the right sort of thing.

@AHaworth Yeah, that answer should be what I need. Thanks for the help tho.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I think you might be able to use the :has()-selector for this. But it is also possible to do it with a flat structur where the elements are in the following order input, label and the img's inside the label. You could then select it by using input:checked + label > .image but I think the :has-selector makes it easier to understand and follow.
Hope this helps you. Let me know if you need anything else or this needs adjustments for your use case.


.canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.image-alt {
  display: none; /* Hide alternative image on default */
}
.image-box input {
  display: none;
}
.image-box:has(input:checked) .image { /* Hide original image if '.image-box' contains a checked input */
  display: none;
}
.image-box:has(input:checked) .image-alt { /* Show alternative image if '.image-box' contains a checked input */
  display: block;
}
<div class="canvas">
  <label class="image-box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100" class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100/100" class="image-alt">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <label class="image-box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100" class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100/100" class="image-alt">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <label class="image-box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100" class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100/100" class="image-alt">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <label class="image-box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100" class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100/100" class="image-alt">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <label class="image-box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/100/100" class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/100/100" class="image-alt">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </label>
  <!-- And so on... -->
</div>




This is exactly what I need, thank you! I would like to understand what you are doing to create this, Ive never used the  tag and the :has() selector. honestly im not sure how most of it works.

A label can toggle an input element. Either the label has a for attribute with the inputs ID or the actual input is inside the label. In this case we use the latter. The :has()-selector checks if the element it is appended to has what is inside the brackets. So in this case it checks has the element with class image-box an input that is checked? If yes apply style to element with class image and on the other line to image-alt inside said image-box element. Hope this helps.

:has()-selector
label-element
