# How to avoid jumping when click on anchor link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show/hide content using purely CSS without JavaScript.  I reached on this solution.

When I click on the link it jump down in page. I need pure CSS solution, how to stop it to jump?

```css
p[id^="detailView-"] {
  display: none;
}

p[id^="detailView-"]:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#detailView-1">Show View1</a>
<p id="detailView-1">View1</p>

<a href="#detailView-2">Show View2</a>
<p id="detailView-2">View2</p>
```

Comment: Please create a minimal example. I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: I'm sure you can find an alternative here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023816/toggle-divs-without-using-javascript

Comment: Are you asking how to stop jump with this solution, or for another solution?

Comment: with this solution. This code working fine according to my requirements the only drawback is jumping down when click on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Just arrange your html so the anchor tags are at the top like so

```css
p[id^="detailView-"] {
  display: none;
}

p[id^="detailView-"]:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#detailView-1">Show View1</a>
<a href="#detailView-2">Show View2</a>

<p id="detailView-1">View1</p>
<p id="detailView-2">View2</p>
```

Comment: IF you could update the original question with this then we can have a look

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, instead of toggling between:

- `display: none`
- `display: block`

you can toggle between:

- `visibility: hidden`
- `visibility: visible`

---

The difference between the two properties is that:

- `visibility` maintains page-space for an element, even when that element is invisible
- `display: none` will actually *remove* the element from the page and collapse the space that it was occupying

---

**Working Example:**

```css
p[id^="detailView-"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

p[id^="detailView-"]:target {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#detailView-1">Show View1</a>
<p id="detailView-1">View1</p>

<a href="#detailView-2">Show View2</a>
<p id="detailView-2">View2</p>
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility